# How to fix 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key' exception using CSOM in SharePoint Online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I trying to retrieve some data from a SharePoint Online site using C#. I have two different SharePoint sites (like site1.sharepoint.com and site2.sharepoint.com). I use the same code to retrieve date and I can retrieve from site1.sharepoint.com and works perfectly, but I cannot retrieve from site2.sharepoint.com.

The site1 is our organization tenant, which means security settings were changed, meanwhile site2 is default(no setting has been changed since it was created).

Can the problem be to the site1? If yes, which settings could generate such error?

Thank you

```
    private async Task<ListItemCollection> GetIntentFilterData(string url, string content, string columnName, string columnValue)
    {
        string siteUrl = url;

        string login = _configuration["Login"];
        string password = _configuration["Password"];

        string listName = content;

        try
        {

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {

                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, password);

                List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format(@"<View>                              
                                                    <Query> 
                                                    <Where>
                                                    <Contains>                                                        
                                                    <FieldRef Name='BaseName'/>                                        
                                                    <Value Type='Lookup'>" + columnValue + @"</Value>                                                                                            
                                                    </Contains>                                                                                                            
                                                    <FieldRef Name='EncodedAbsUrl'/>                                           
                                                    <Value Type='Lookup'>" + columnValue + @"</Value>                                                                                                                                                  
                                                    </Where>                                
                                                    </Query>                                                    
                                                    </View>", "Some specific item");

                ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(item => item["EncodedAbsUrl"], item => item["BaseName"]));

                await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(); // this line throws the exception.
                return collListItem;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // The error is "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key"
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I am expecting the same result I get form the site2 (a list of files).
The result I am getting now is

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stack overflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your exception details as **text** rather than as a screen shot?  Stack Overflow policy is that you should include your code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812).